# Any good explanation why $\sigma(\tau f)=(\sigma\tau)f$ holds.

Tags: permutations, intuition

I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.

The following proposition and its proof are in this book:

> Let $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a mulitivariable polynomial.
> We define $\sigma f$ as $$(\sigma f)(x_1,\dots,x_n):=f(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)}).$$
> Then $\sigma(\tau f)=(\sigma\tau)f$ holds.

> Proof:
> $$(\sigma(\tau f))(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(\tau f)(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})\\
> =f(x_{\sigma(\tau(1))},\dots,x_{\sigma(\tau(n))})\\
> =f(x_{(\sigma\tau)(1)},\dots,x_{(\sigma\tau)(n)})\\
> =((\sigma\tau)f)(x_1,\dots,x_n).$$

$(\tau f)(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})=f(x_{\sigma(\tau(1))},\dots,x_{\sigma(\tau(n))})$ is correct.
$(\tau f)(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})=f(x_{\tau(\sigma(1))},\dots,x_{\tau(\sigma(n))})$ is wrong.
I am very confused.

My interpretation of this proof is the following:

> The $i$ th variable of $\mu f$ is the $\mu^{-1}(i)$ th variable of $f$.
>
> The $i$ th variable of $\sigma(\tau f)$ is the $\sigma^{-1}(i)$ th variable of $\tau f$.
> The $\sigma^{-1}(i)$ th variable of $\tau f$ is the $\tau^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(i))$ th variable of $f$.
> The $\tau^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(i))$ th variable of $f$ is the $(\sigma\tau)^{-1}(i)$ th variable of $f$.
> So, the $i$ th variable of $\sigma(\tau f)$ is the $(\sigma\tau)^{-1}(i)$ th variable of $f$.
>
> The $i$ th variable of $(\sigma\tau)f$ is the $(\sigma\tau)^{-1}(i)$ th variable of $f$.
>
> So, the $i$ th variable of $\sigma(\tau f)$ is the $i$ th variable of $(\sigma\tau)f$.
> So, $\sigma(\tau f)=(\sigma\tau)f$.

Why $(\tau f)(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})=f(x_{\sigma(\tau(1))},\dots,x_{\sigma(\tau(n))})$ holds?
Any good explanation?

Comment: Look at a simple example, like $f=X_1X_2+X_2X_3$ and $\tau=(1~2),\sigma=(2~3)$. Then $\tau f=X_2X_1+X_1X_3$, and then $\sigma(\tau f)=X_3X_1+X_1X_2$. See that this is $(\sigma\tau)f$

Comment: The book's proof is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon Satake's proof a bit, let's focus on what happens to the $n$-tuple $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ before getting evaluated under $f$. Define $\tilde{\sigma} \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$\tilde{\sigma}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = (x_{\sigma(1)}, x_{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)}).$$
We can show that $\widetilde{\sigma \tau} = \tilde{\tau} \circ \tilde{\sigma}$: given $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n) = \tilde{\sigma}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ and $(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n) = (\tilde{\tau} \circ \tilde{\sigma})(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$. Then
\begin{align}
(\tilde{\tau} \circ \tilde{\sigma})(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) & = (z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n) \\
& = (y_{\tau(1)}, y_{\tau(2)}, \ldots, y_{\tau(n)}) \\
& = (y_{(\sigma^{-1}\sigma)(\tau(1))}, y_{(\sigma^{-1}\sigma)(\tau(2))}, \ldots, y_{(\sigma^{-1}\sigma)(\tau(n))}) \\
& = (y_{\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(\tau(1)))}, y_{\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(\tau(2)))}, \ldots, y_{\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(\tau(n)))}) \\
& = (y_{\sigma^{-1}((\sigma\tau)(1))}, y_{\sigma^{-1}((\sigma\tau)(2))}, \ldots, y_{\sigma^{-1}((\sigma\tau)(n))}) \\
& = (x_{\sigma(\sigma^{-1}((\sigma\tau)(1)))}, x_{\sigma(\sigma^{-1}((\sigma\tau)(2)))}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(\sigma^{-1}((\sigma\tau)(n)))}) \\
& = (x_{(\sigma\sigma^{-1})((\sigma\tau)(1))}, x_{(\sigma\sigma^{-1})((\sigma\tau)(2))}, \ldots, x_{(\sigma\sigma^{-1})((\sigma\tau)(n))}) \\
& = (x_{(\sigma\tau)(1)}, x_{(\sigma\tau)(2)}, \ldots, x_{(\sigma\tau)(n)}) \\
& = \widetilde{\sigma\tau}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n),
\end{align}
showing $\tilde{\sigma\tau} = \tilde{\tau} \circ \tilde{\sigma}$.

Now for any function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ (polynomial or otherwise), $\sigma f = f \circ \tilde{\sigma}$, so associativity of function composition shows
$$(\sigma \tau)f = f \circ \widetilde{\sigma \tau} = f \circ (\tilde{\tau} \circ \tilde{\sigma}) = (f \circ \tilde{\tau}) \circ \tilde{\sigma} = (\tau f) \circ \tilde{\sigma} = \sigma(\tau f).$$

(Note that Satake uses the convention that $\sigma \tau = \sigma \circ \tau$.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Hayden.